# HTML page seems to add iframe element when opening chrome by selenium in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium and web automation tasks, and I am trying to code an application for automating papers search on PubMed, using chromedriver.

My aim is to click the top right "Sign in" button in the PubMed main page, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed. So the problem is:

- when I open PubMed main page manually, there are no iframes tags in the html source, and therefore the "Sign in" element should be simply accessible by its xpath `"//*[@id="sign_in"]"`.
- when same page is openened by selenium instead, I cannot find that "Sign in" element by its xpath, and if a try to inspect it, the html source seems to have embedded it in an `<iframe>` tag, so that it cannot be found anymore unless a `driver._switch_to.frame` method is executed. But if I open the html source code by `Ctrl+U`and search for `<iframe>` element, there is still none of them. Here is the "Sign in" element inspection capture:

```
["Sign in" inspection][1]
```

I already got round this problem by:

```
bot = PubMedBot()
bot.driver.get('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed')
sleep(2)
frames = bot.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
bot.driver._switch_to.frame(frames[0])
btn = bot.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/a')
btn.click()
```

But all I would like to understand is why the inspection code is different from the html source code, whether this `<iframe>` element is really appearing from nowhere, and if so why.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing issue due to synchronization .Kinddly find below solution to resolve your issue:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"path ofchromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed")
iframe = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Sign in to NCBI')]"))).click()
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Inspect element:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand your solution since you switch to the correct frame, but I am not still understanding why that element is being embedded in an iframe if it wasn´t in manually openend page.

Comment: If you inspect your element after manully launching https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed url then you will get to know its inside the iframe.  and it's not with manual/automation, sign in element always embedded with iframe only . With selenium we need to switch control to iframe befoore interating with it

Comment: If I launch  <ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed> url and inspect the element I cannot find any `<iframe>` tag. How can I know it is inside an `iframe`?

Comment: check attached screens shot in answer section : Inspect element:

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer and hit upvote button from your endfrom your end.

Comment: Still not seeing the same source as you and can't figure out that iframe, surely because of my lack of experience. Thank you very much again!